# Another term for "transgender children"

Tags: american-english, synonyms

Is there another expression besides "transgender" that is widely accepted in US English for children of all ages and both sexes, which deal with doubts about their gender and body while they grow up?

Wikipedia offers many options:

- Agender / genderless
- Androgyne
- Bigender
- Genderqueer / Non-binary
- Gender bender
- Hijra
- Pangender
- Queer heterosexuality
- Third gender
- Trans man
- Trans woman
- Transmasculine
- Transfeminine
- Trigender
- Two-Spirit…

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transgender_youth

I am not sure if any of those is specifically for children, and I need one meant for children.

How would be called a child in US English, who wants a sex change, but not for the same reason as other transgender children (he grieves after his sister, feels guilty for her death and wants to replace her, so his parents remain together)?

It is a script idea I am working on at the moment.

Comment: Not sure there is one specifically for kids but perhaps "[Gender Dysphoria](https://www.psychiatry.org/patients-families/gender-dysphoria/what-is-gender-dysphoria)" might be useful.

Comment: @Roger Thanks. I will try to use it in the logline.

Comment: I would say "children with gender dysphoria" until such a time as the person has self identified themselves with another label such as transgender.

Answer (score 1):

If the word existed, Wiki wouldn't need to use an acronym: **GIDC**. It'd at least have a more scientific sounding name like, *Adolescent Gender Dysphoria*, but that would exclude anyone who's prepubescent, which is probably why it's not.

**[Gender dysphoria in children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_dysphoria_in_children)** –Wiki

> **Gender dysphoria in children** or **gender identity disorder in children (GIDC)** is a formal diagnosis used by psychologists and physicians to describe children who experience significant discontent (gender dysphoria) with their biological sex, assigned gender, or both.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an expression used exclusively for children. *Trans kids*, *Gender nonconforming kids*, and *Gender Questioning kids* are the only ones I can think of, however, it seems like that's not the case of the child you're describing. Labelling your character as trans might be inappropriate.

https://srlp.org/resources/fact-sheet-transgender-gender-nonconforming-youth-school/
http://www.transkidspurplerainbow.org

Answer (score -2):

All children go through this at some point, so there was never a need to come up with a word for it. Children change their gender an estimated seven times before the age of six, it's part of play and self-discovery.